# UTF 8 encoding working in FF but not working in IE

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

I have the following issue:
i have a form that receives through GET special characters. It reads them and then it fills the fields with these characters.
I have the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` inserted right under `<head>`.
Everything works perfect in FF but in IE the characters are messed up and i get all these � signs instead.
However,in IE if i right click on the page and under encoding i change UTF-8 to Western European(Windows) these characters are correctly displayed.
I've also tried to add the `AddDefaultCharset Off` in my Apache conf file just to be sure the web server doesn't overwrite the charset encoding.
The weird thing is that, if in my code i use PHP's `htmlentities` then the text displays correctly in IE but wrong in FF.

More than this, i've used firebug and ie developer tools to see how the GET data is passed and it seems that in FF the special characters are converted like: `B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%9F%C3%96%C3%84%C3%9C%20IT%20%C3%A0%C3%A8%C3%AC%C3%B2%C3%B9%20` but in IT the GET data shows as `àéèâêîôûœïç`.

Can anyone help me with this? It's starting to get really frustrating not finding a way in that FF and also IE works.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have trouble with GET URLs like

```
 emeasmartportal.com/sbso/index-test.php?fname=àéèâêîôûœïç
```

It looks like ythe problem is the incoming GET data itself: because they have to encode it *before they can know what character set the responding page has*, browsers use different default encodings for that data. Firefox seems to use UTF-8 by default (see e.g. this bug report). IE doesn't seem to do that.

I think what you need to do is use `mb_detect_encoding()` to detect whether the incoming data is IS-8859-1 or UTF-8. (This specific case can be reliably detected using that function.)

If the incoming data is ISO-8859-1 (which you can detect reliably using mb_detect_encoding) you need to convert it:

```
iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $data)
```

if it's already UTF-8, you don't.

This *should* work, but no guarantees. Encoding issues can be nasty when you don't know the incoming encoding for sure.

Comment: Maybe i'm just stupid but for instance, in firebug i'm not how or where to see the chaaracter set header sent by my server. What i see is:Content-Type text/html , Transfer-Encoding chunked, Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5  . I'm using Apache 2.2 on windows server 2008.

Comment: http://emeasmartportal.com/sbso/index-test.php?fname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&lname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&cid=1-1Q9-2406&coid=1-10EXOC&partname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&lang=de   if you'll open this link the fname parameter will show up correctly in FF but wrong in IE (i'm not doing any kind of encoding/decoding on it) . lname will show up correctly in IE but wrong in FF (i'm doing htmlentities on the GET data)

Comment: Well i would like to but i'm not sure how to do this. I've tried adding the AddDefaultCharset directive in my conf file and also on the .htaccess file but i'm not sure if this is the correct way. Does it also happen to you as well?

Comment: @Mihai to clarify - where exactly are the characters breaking? If I choose, say, Spanish as a language, should I be getting broken characters? Because it seems to work for me in IE9

Comment: The broken characters are the ones sent via GET. So if you copy the whole link with all those characters, they should break in IE or FF. All the other labels of the form are working correctly.

Comment: Can you paste the link again? I'm not sure what in the above is part of the link, and what is not. I'm using `http://emeasmartportal.com/sbso/index-test.php?fname=FR` and it seems fine?

Comment: http://emeasmartportal.com/sbso/index-test.php?fname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&lname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&cid=1-1Q9-2406&coid=1-10EXOC&partname=FR àéèâêîôûœïç DE öäüßÖÄÜ IT àèìòù ES ñáéíóú&lang=de

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8389/discussion-between-mihai-ila-and-pekka)